# How to remove an object from state(and LocalStorage) in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to Redux/React. I have been trying to add a function that would remove objects from the state(and LocalStorage) and failed so far. I think the problem is that I cannot extract an individual object from 'this.props.weather' (which is an array) and pass it as an argument to 'removeItem' function'. In the Action Creator as well the 'location' argument is actually a list not an object. Also I am not sure about the reducer.  I was wondering if somebody could have a look and tell me what I am doing wrong. 
Thank you very much.

### Weather List Container ##

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import Chart from '../components/Chart.jsx';
import Google_map from '../components/Google_map.jsx';
import {removeItem} from '../actions/index.js';

class WeatherList extends React.Component{

 handleRemoveItem = () => {      
 if (typeof this.props.removeItem === 'function') {
 this.props.removeItem(this.props.weather)
}
console.log('remove click works')    
}

 renderWeather=(cityData)=>{
    const name=cityData.city.name;
    const temps=cityData.list.map(weather=>weather.main.temp);
    const pressures=cityData.list.map(weather=>weather.main.pressure);
    const humidities = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.humidity);
    const {lon, lat}=cityData.city.coord;

    return <tr key={name} id={name}>
                    <td><Google_map lon={lon} lat={lat}/></td>
                    <td><Chart data={temps} color='orange' units='C'/></td>
                    <td><Chart data={pressures} color='blue' units='hPa'/</td>
                    <td><Chart data={humidities} color='green' units='%'/</td>
                    <td><span className='input-group-btn'>
                        <button className ='btn btn-secondary'
                           onClick{this.handleRemoveItem}>Remove
                        </button>
                        </span>
                   </td>
            </tr>
   }
   render(){
    return <table className='table table-hover'>
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>City</th>
                     <th>Temperature (C)</th>
                     <th>Pressure (hPa)</th>
                     <th>Humidity (%)</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  {this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}
              </tbody>
           </table>
  }
 }
 function mapStateToProps ({weather}){
      return {weather};

}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
      return bindActionCreators({removeItem}, dispatch);
}
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WeatherList);
```

### Action Creator

```
  export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';
  export const REMOVE_ITEM='REMOVE_ITEM';

  export function fetchWeather(city) {
     const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city}`;
     const request = axios.get(url);
     return {type: FETCH_WEATHER, payload: request};
   }

export function removeItem(location){
      return {
         type: REMOVE_ITEM, 
         payload: location, 
        }               
 }
```

### Reducer

```
  import {REMOVE_ITEM} from '../actions/index.js';
  export default function (state = [], action) {
       switch (action.type) {
       case REMOVE_ITEM:
             const index=state.filter(item=> city===action)
             return [...state.slice(0, index),
                    ...state.slice(index+1)];

       }
        return state;
       }
```

### Reducers Combined

```
 import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
 import WeatherReducer from './reducer_weather.js';
 import RemoveItem from './reducer_removeItem.js';
 const rootReducer=combineReducers({
     weather: WeatherReducer,
     removeItem: RemoveItem,
   }
 );

 export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: I think your `filter` syntax is wrong. Shouldn't it be: `const index=state.filter(item=> item === action.payload)` ?

Comment: Thank you! I changed it but it is still not working.